# geting convexhull using longitude and longitude PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to generate the coordinates of the convexhull using points i entered in a table.

this is how I created the table

```
CREATE TABLE map5(id VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY,
              points geometry);
```

And this is how I entered the points

```
Insert into map5 (id,id2, points) VALUES ('LeaveyLibrary',
'1',ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.282866 34.021845)', 4326));
Insert into map5 (id, id2,points) VALUES ('TommyTrojan', 
'1',ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.2876357 34.0205621)', 4326));
Insert into map5 (id, id2,points) VALUES ('DohenyLibrary', 
'1',ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.2849868 34.0201529)', 4326));
Insert into map5 (id, id2,points) VALUES ('VKCLibrary', 
'1',ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.2843347 34.0205791)', 4326));
```

This is how I generate the convexhull

```
SELECT st_astext(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(points::geometry))) as points 
from map5 group by id;
```

However it only return points instead of polygon, what did i do wrong in here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just the ConcaveHull as one geom, your query must be like this:

```
Select ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(d.geom),1) As geom
FROM points As d
```

In your case:

```
Select st_astext(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(points::geometry),1)) As polygon
FROM map5
```

The result:

[image]